# Oracle UPDATE with two subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle

how to get access to table which i want to update in second subquery?
Let me explain, i have that update query:

```
UPDATE someTbl tbl
SET
    x_price = (
        SELECT
            substr(
                func.x_price,
                7,
                instr(
                    func.x_price,
                    '=',
                    7
                ) - 7
            )
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    somePackage.someFunction(
                        pbi.product_id,
                        pbi.x_sset_id,
                        pbi.inst_prod_id,
                        SYSDATE,
                        '',
                        '',
                        '',
                        ''
                    ) AS x_price
                FROM
                    someTbl pbi
            ) func
    );
```

And i have to create conditions which limit the second subquery, because i get

`ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row`

I need to build condition which define relation between main table `tbl` and second subquery `func`
I'm beginner in oracle sql. Could you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Message "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row" return when result trust is single-row but result is multi row, Above set field statement value must is one row one value!!!

Sorry English is bad

Comment: Yes that's what i'm talking about. Second subquery returns multi row but i have to write condition which limit it to one row. I want to update all rows in table someTbl by using substr and function someFunction

Comment: Set command basic can not set multiple values to one field while running one command,  ex: update  A set id = 1, when field id is grant equals 1 for all row

Answer (score 0):

You need to correlate the two queries:

```
UPDATE someTbl tbl
SET x_price = (
        SELECT substr( x_price, 7, instr( x_price, '=', 7 ) - 7 )
        FROM   (
          SELECT somePackage.someFunction(
                   product_id,
                   x_sset_id,
                   inst_prod_id,
                   SYSDATE,
                   '',
                   '',
                   '',
                   ''
                 ) AS x_price,
                 your_primary_key              -- Add primary key to inner query
          FROM   someTbl
        ) func
        WHERE tbl.your_primary_key = func.your_primary_key
                                               -- Add filter to outer query which will
                                               -- correlate the rows from the update and
                                               -- the sub-query.
    );
```

Otherwise, your sub-query is returning all the rows of the table.